# Is "defer" guaranteed to be called in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

According to Apple Swift documentation **defer**

> This statement lets you do any necessary cleanup that should be performed regardless of how execution leaves the current block of code whether it leaves because an error was thrown or because of a statement such as return or break.

[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID514)

But this code:

```
enum SomeError: ErrorType {
    case BadLuck
}

func unluckey() throws {
    print("\n\tunluckey() -> someone will have a bad day ;)\n")
    throw SomeError.BadLuck
}

func callsUnluckey() throws {

    print("callsUnluckey() -> OPENING something")
    defer {
        print("callsUnluckey() -> CLOSEING something")
    }

    print("callsUnluckey() -> WORKING with something")

    try unluckey()
    print("callsUnluckey() -> will never get here so chill...")

    defer {
        print("callsUnluckey() -> why this is not getting called?")
    }
}

do {
    try callsUnluckey()
} catch {
    print("")
    print("someone had a bad day")
}
```

Produces this result in the console:

```
callsUnluckey() -> OPENING something
callsUnluckey() -> WORKING with something

    unluckey() -> someone will have a bad day ;)

callsUnluckey() -> CLOSEING something

someone had a bad day
```

And my question is: **why the last defer in callsUnluckey() is not getting called?**.

Comment: Can you point me to any documentation about that? :) Or any information about how those blocks are getting scheduled?

Comment: Well I think it's very clear that "that's just how programs work" ;) I could even guess that they are getting "stacked" during runtime not compilation time. But that could be still only a guess ;)

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at the language grammar, as summarized in [*The Swift Programming Language*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AboutTheLanguageReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH29-ID345):`defer` is a *statement*. In the grammar, a statement is imperative code to be run in order (as opposed to the definition of a program element, like a class or function, to be later used in imperative code).

Note also the bit right after the part you quoted, on order dependence. If `defer` was just a declaration, like a function or property or type declaration, there couldn't be an ordering effect. (It doesn't matter what order you put function declarations in, for example.)

IIRC (on mobile right now, can't check easily), the compiler will catch you if you put a `defer` after a `return`, noting that it is code that will never be executed.

Remember that "throwing" in Swift is, under the hood, really just a special kind of return type. So if your function `throw`s, no code after the `throw` will be executed (and thus no `defer` statement will be able to set up a code block to be later executed). When you declare a function `throws`, any call in it to another throwing function effectively becomes a possible `throw` statement, which itself is effectively a return.

Comment: The way I understand your answer is that when  unluckey() throws it's like a "return" for callsUnluckey(). The dock says ->
"The statements within the defer statement are executed no matter how program control is transferred." The way I see it when the scope of the callsUnluckey() ends it should call the last "defer". But it's not getting called and I don't understand why :) 

(https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/defer-statement)

Comment: Note also that the compiler would mark the defer after a return statement as a code that will be never executed :) Can you point me to a place where I can check how "defer is implemented"? :D

Comment: The doc should probably say something more like, "*once a defer statement has appeared*, the statements within are execute no matter how program control is transferred thereafter."

Comment: I agree that the docs should be more specific about that :) But still the how defer works is a secret ;)  Are those blocks copied someplace on a stack/heap (rather heap if that's the case) or compiled :) I can't find anything about that anywhere ;) And yes I am looking on the github swift repo ;)

Comment: Think of `defer` as a stack operation. Any defer block needs to be "put on to the defer stack". If that code never gets run than there is no "defer block" to pop. This make sens as defer is designed as "clean up code". So if the code earlier "failed" than there 's no sense in calling a clean up code :)

Answer (score 1):

The last defer is not called because it is declared after `try unluckey()` which throws an error.  The execution pointer inside `func callsUnluckey()` hasn't reached this last `defer` statement before the function has exited.